# How to change store id?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I know how to change customer increment id & order increment id. But I require to change magento store id. How to achieve this? My magento community version is 1.7.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried changing the store ID but you can access the store ID from your Magento Database in the table `core_store`.